# How to type \ as a string?

Tags: python, string

I have a variable containing folderpath in format `C:/folder/folder`. I need to covert it into `C:\folder\folder`. I tried this script: `folder_path = folder_path.replace("/", "\")`, but the last `"\"` is being interpeted by something other than a string containing character: `\`

How do I tell python I literarily whant only charater `\` in a string?

Comment: Did you mean: `"\\"`?

Comment: always helpful: [the tutorials](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings)

Comment: @quamrana Yes. That was it exatcly. I knew I know it but coudl not remember the syntax and was looking for it for about hour. Many thanks!

Comment: Really, the best way to deal with paths is to use `pathlib.Path` objects and not worry about slashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use two \ instead of one \ since \ is escape character

```
a = "C:/folder/folder"
b = a.replace("/", "\\")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use either an escape sequence `'\\'` like so:

```
path = 'C:\\something\\another'
```

Or you can use "raw strings":

```
path = r'C:\something\another'
```

The documentation about raw strings and escape patterns is listed [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)